# Execute code block per column with group_id vs whole table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this block of code that works perfectly, thanks to a little help from McNets, until I add a group column.
I’ve been attempting multiple ways to use a window clause and subqueries but haven’t found a workable solution yet.

I have been working on this for hours – at this point, I think I might be too close to the code to see the light…
Where am I going wrong?

I have included a pic of the good and bad results. Each group should have the same values. 
Using PostgreSQL 9.6

```
create table range (low int, hight int);
create table keys (keynum int);
insert into range values (3,12),(6,9),(24,40);
insert into keys values (1),(4),(7),(10),(13),(16),(19),(22),(25),(28),(31),(34),(37),(40),(43);
```

Code that works without grp column:

```
select low, hight, count(k.*)
from   keys k
join   range r
on     keynum between low and hight
group by low, hight
```

Code that fails when adding grp column:

```
select grp, low, hight, count(*) over(partition by grp)
from   keys k
join   range r
on     keynum between low and hight
group by grp, low, hight
order by grp, low, hight
```

subquery also fails:

```
select * from (
    select grp, low, hight, count(*)
    from   keys k
    join   range r
    on     keynum between low and hight
--where grp = 2
group by grp, low, hight
order by grp, low, hight) t
```

[image: results without grp column]

[image: results with grp column]

[results using subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bPvj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `group by`, you don't need a window function.  Is this what you want?

```
select grp, low, hight, count(*)
from keys k join
     range r
    on keynum between low and hight
group by grp, low, hight
order by grp, low, hight;
```

The window function, `count(*) over (partition by grp)` is counting the number of rows *after the aggregation* for each `grp` value.  There are three rows.  That is where the "3" comes from.

Comment: It's executing the code on the whole table rather than individual groups. I'm using **group by** but I'm not getting separation in the result column (count).  Oop, yes you are correct it is count rows per group.

Comment: It's when I wrap it in a subquery that it looks at the whole table with 3,1, 6 as the result per group.

Comment: Sorry Gordon I misread your reply. Your code is reading the whole table also. Each group should have 3,18,9 in the [count] column if it's parsing correctly.

Comment: @Phil_in_Tx . . . Do you just want `hight - low`?

Comment: Gordon, I’m not sure what you are asking.  The goal is to count how many times keynum is within each rows range (determined by low & hight). Which worked fine until I add the “within grp” criteria.  What is not included in the resulting table output is the keynum field.